# Change store in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, store

How can I change data in my 'gridpanel' store?

I try to do this :

```
cellclick: function (th, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
                    record.set('hasPast', '-');
                    th.getStore().insert(rowIndex + 1, record.data.pastRecal);
    }
```

But it give error!
'cellclick' -  listener of cell click event on my grid.

**Error from ext-all-debug.js(in this code segment):**

```
urlAppend : function(url, string) {
            if (!Ext.isEmpty(string)) {
                return url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + string;
            }

            return url;
        },
```

**url is undefined**

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too vague. If there's an error, what is it?

Comment: do you want to change the data in a store, or change the whole store?

Answer (score 0):

It tries to make a query to some remote source, but your store proxy is not configured properly. Usually you get such error when you switch from Memory to some kind of Remote store (AJAX or other). Just check closely your store and proxy configuration and you'll find an error there.

Try to set that property to your store and see the diffirence:

```
autoSync: false
```

If you need more details you should post your store and proxy configuration.

Good luck!